# Why DISPID_NEWPROCESS event not trigger?

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

IE should trigger this event when a new process of IE is about to create as descripted in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288084(v=vs.85).aspx. But I can't get this notification when a new process is created, why? I'm using IE8. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ExDispid.h from SDK:

```
#define DISPID_NEWPROCESS 284 // Fired when a navigation must be redirected due to Protected Mode
```

It looks description in MSDN is not correct.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to get notified when a new IE process is about to be created whatever if it is in protected mode. Is this possible?

Comment: What you want to do when you catch such event?

Comment: I want to share data to the created IE process. But it seems that this is impossible as even I get the notification I still don't know the new process ID. So, I think I should consider to choose other way. Anyway, thanks to all of your comments.